# Logstash aggregation based on 'temporary id'

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm not sure if this sort of aggregation is best done after being indexed by elasticsearch or if logstash is a good place to do it.

We are logging information about commands run against a server. Each set of metrics regarding a single command is logged as a single log event, there are multiple 'metric sets' per command. Each metric is of its own document type in ES (currently at least). So we will have multiple events across multiple documents regarding one command run against the server.

Each of these events will have a 'cmdno' field which is a temporary id given to the command we are logging about. Once the command has finished with all events logged, the 'cmdno' may be reused for other commands.

Is it possible to use logstash 'aggregate' plugin to link the events of a single command together using the 'cmdno'? (or any plugin)

All events that pertain to a single command will have the same timestamp + cmdno. I would like to add a UUID to the events as a permanent unique id for that command, so that a single query will give us all events for that single command.

Was thinking along the lines of:

```
if [cmdno] {
    aggregate {
        task_id => "%{cmdno}"
        code => "map['cmdid'] ||= <some uuid generator>; event['cmdid'] == map['cmdid'] ? event['@timestamp'] == map['<stored timestamp for previous event from the same command>'] : continue"
    }
}
```

Just started learning the ELK stack, not entirely sure as to the programming contructs logstash affords me yet.

I don't know if there is a better way to relate these events, this seemed the most suitable for our needs, if there are more ELK'y methods please let me know, they do need to stay as separate documents of different types though.

Any help much appreciated, let me know if I am missing anything.

Cheers,

Brett